# Allure Team City plugin

Tags: teamcity, allure

I am using an allure teamcity plugin to generate allure report. 
The problem is that autogenerated `executor.json` file by plugin contains an invalid teamcity base url. Right now the url is a local ip address. So I can not navigate back to teamcity server from generated report because the ip adress is not resolved

I am expected to see an outer ip address in the `executor.json` file to resolve problem.

I have tried to set up a server url as below

[image: Set up a server ulr]

but that doesn't help.

How can I set up a base url in the auto-generated `executor.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [source code](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-teamcity/blob/master/allure-teamcity-agent/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/teamcity/AllureBuildServiceAdapter.java) we need to set up `teamcity.serverUrl` parameter at the build agent. It can be done using the [build configuration topic](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Agent+Configuration)